# Error on creating menu

Tags: android

I have a scroll view element and inside it a table element in my android application.I want to insert a menu element too.But when i place menu inside Scroll View I got this error "Scroll View can have only one child". where can I fix my menu and how?

Here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#eef1f5" >

<menu>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/new_game"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="new_game"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:title="help"/>
</menu>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b3 "
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Connect" />

        <Button
            android1:id="@+id/b1 "
            android1:layout_width="0dip"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:text="Retrive Data" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2 "
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Close" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/systemId"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="SysId" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/systemId1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/opMode"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Model" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/opMode1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DCTime"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="DCTimer" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/DCTime1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Ups"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="UPS" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Ups1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Mode"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Mode " >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Mode1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/LFBD"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LFBD" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/LFBD1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Hybrid"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Hybrid" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Hybrid1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PHC"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="PHC" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/PHC1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Now"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Now" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Now1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/GridCharging"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="GRID_CHRG" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/GridCharging1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SolarCharging"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="SOLR_CHRG" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/SolarCharging1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Trip"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Trip" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Trip1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/APSS"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="APSS" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/APSS1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TPSS"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TPSS" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/TPSS1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TPSSValue"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="AC_TIMER " >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/TPSSValue1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/BV"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Bat_Volt" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/BV1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SV"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Sol_Volt" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/SV1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TCT"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TCT" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/TCT1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Main"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Main_Volt" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Main1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Load"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Load" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Load1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Amps"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Amps" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Amps1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:enabled="false" />
    </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>

  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: ScrollView can have only one direct child. You need to wrap menu and TableLayout in other layout.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap all of the child elements inside a single LinearLayout. You will need to set the height (and probably width) to 'wrap_content'.